# How to send the pdf file from the assets folder

Tags: android, pdf

I am not able to send a pdf file via email or WhasApp on Android. Below is my code to send the pdf file -- what's wrong with it?

```
 File file = new File("android.resource://beeonline.com.chromatography/raw/vendormumbai.pdf");

 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
 intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sharing Mumbai  File...");
 intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sharing File...");
 try {
      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share PDF file"));
 } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
      Toast.makeText(ActivityshowVendorForm.this, "Error: Cannot open or share created PDF report.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Comment: hi please help as i m not able to send the pdf file via mail or watsup android and above is my code to send the pdf file m i wrong some where

Answer (score 0):

First, your question title refers to assets. Your code has nothing to do with assets.

Second, `android.resource://mypackagename/raw/vendormumbai.pdf` is not a file path, just as `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222995/how-to-send-the-pdf-file-from-the-assets-folder-via-share-option-in-mail-or-wats` is not a file path. Your value is a string representation of a `Uri`, pointing to a raw resource (not an asset).

You are welcome to try replacing:

```
File file = new File("android.resource://mypackagename/raw/vendormumbai.pdf");

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
```

with:

```
Uri thing = Uri.parse("android.resource://mypackagename/raw/vendormumbai.pdf");

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setDataAndType(thing,"application/pdf");
```

That should work better, but the `android.resource` scheme is uncommon, so not all `ACTION_SEND` recipients will recognize it. Also, this assumes that you are using raw resources, not assets.

If you really want to serve the PDF from assets, or if `android.resource` is not supported by the apps you want, you can try [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider), which offers a `ContentProvider` that, among other things, can serve assets and raw resources using a `content` `Uri`.

Or, you can implement your own `ContentProvider` that can serve the file from `assets/` or `res/raw/`.

Or, you can copy the asset (or raw resource) to a local file (e.g., in `getFilesDir()` or `getCacheDir()`), [then use `FileProvider` to serve that local file](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider).

Comment: hi the above code is not working do you have more reference i am able to show the pdf file now the only thing i want is to share that particular pdf file.